# face_recognition encoding from string back to original encoding in python

Tags: python, encoding, face-recognition, dlib

I am exploring face_recognition in python https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition

Currently, I store the face_encoding in a string. You can see how I'ved converted in a string array so that I can save it in the database.

```
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
face_location_unknown = face_recognition.face_locations(unknown_image)
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image, face_location_unknown)[0]


#conversion to string
unknown_encoding_string = "%s" % unknown_encoding
face_unknown_encoding_string = re.sub('\s+', ', ', unknown_encoding_string[1:-1])
```

The "face_unknown_encoding_string" is like this:

```
"-0.127419,0.0709146,0.0794749,-0.0321613,-0.0159098,0.00918037,-0.0360131,-0.0601268,0.0995623,-0.106627,0.253107,-0.00910004,-0.236208,-0.164839,0.0281254,0.173948,-0.157076,-0.099059,-0.0318014,-0.0617558,0.0104656,-0.00391768,0.0300188,0.082264,-0.116754,-0.42047,-0.112592,-0.124656,-0.0288262,-0.0780776,-0.0982438,0.0630722,-0.158208,-0.00986074,-0.044616,0.0979513,0.00402067,-7.38486e-05,0.140721,0.0392284,-0.180724,0.011891,0.000132522,0.247319,0.166832,0.0565608,0.022775,-0.0209147,0.040387,-0.172158,0.087646,0.134213,0.0793414,0.0392115,0.00153742,-0.118472,-0.0423868,0.0155273,-0.114884,0.0150463,-0.0130648,-0.136907,-0.0396041,-0.0299826,0.192542,0.107253,-0.102995,-0.147908,0.133909,-0.149223,-0.0397335,0.046862,-0.158645,-0.165123,-0.318725,0.13189,0.36383,0.134758,-0.162269,0.0299262,-0.12019,-0.0473435,0.0974606,0.13637,-0.0189891,0.00880722,-0.0928411,0.063979,0.139967,-0.0451124,-0.0430897,0.214811,-0.0380436,0.131413,0.0137761,0.0366569,-0.0442467,0.0497605,-0.0790947,0.00948556,0.0879658,-0.0556417,0.00738802,0.0854838,-0.15242,0.0731073,0.0232722,0.00448165,0.0829161,0.0995341,-0.163955,-0.143655,0.125336,-0.239622,0.174127,0.243117,0.0262358,0.122618,0.137583,0.109123,-0.00857285,-0.074666,-0.184109,0.00498615,0.131001,0.0170561,0.0319808,0.0229446,",
```

question is how can I convert this

```
face_unknown_encoding_string
```

back into the encoding format same as "unknown_encoding" ?

The reason is I want to now do a compare using "compare_faces"

Comment: That sounds awful (string-based comparison). I never touched that lib, but face-distance should always be based on numerical-calculations (usually floating-point) and not string-based. It seems there is even an example to do it right [there](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/7e454d7a28a06a886313c2a2a68bf11dee57d95b/examples/face_distance.py) (i totally ignored whatever encoding is used; but the example shows a dedicated distance-function; so all good)

Comment: i know but the reason for this is storage.

Comment: What storage? Strings are less efficient in terms of storage. If you want to serialize those encodings, look up what those are (lists vs. numpy arrays) and act according to that (binary pickle vs. numpy's methods; if needed: compression -> but gain depends on the encoding).

Comment: currently the design is storing these strings in the database, well if there is a better way do let me know but the current need is to reconvert it back to the respective encodings

Comment: I already did. Google python + serialization. Of course this somewhat depends on what your DB-API needs. The takeaway-message here is: if the string is human-readable, it's probably very inefficient (and sometimes harder to invert).

Comment: ok, i think the encoding array is in numpy. but unsure since im not an expert in this. will look into it. on a better way of storing aka serialization, etc, i think have to look into it later, since data is stored as such in this particular string format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

God that commenter is useless.

I had a very similar problem where I needed to compare a bunch of serialized face encodings to a new one to see if it's the same person, solved thus:

```
face_recognition.compare_faces(np.array(json.loads(person.face_encodings)), np.array(json.loads(unrecognized_rectangle.face_encoding)))
```